# Is it possible to "intercept" read/writes of a process?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, filesystems, kernel, kernel-module

I have recently discovered "fs_usage" which seems extremely useful.

I was wondering, along the same lines, is it possible to intercept the interaction of a process with the operating system? (to run it in a "sand box" mode for example, if the program tells "write address X", I write to address Y instead. and if program tells "read address X", I read address Y and return that etc, basically have full control on what a process I run can do to my computer or sees from my computer)

Comment: Of course it's possible, that's what debuggers do! If you're talking about Linux, that's ptrace(2): https://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace

Comment: Nice! thats what I was looking for, thank you. Apparently for mac its dtrace. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

good article I found: http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible, that's what debuggers do! If you're talking about Linux, that's [ptrace(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace). On Mac, that's [dtrace](https://8thlight.com/blog/colin-jones/2015/11/06/dtrace-even-better-than-strace-for-osx.html).